# Numpy : Calculating the average of values between two indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to calculate the average of values that are between 2 indices. Lets say my indices are 3 and 10, and i would like to sum up all the values between them and divide by the number of values.

Easiest way would be just using a for loop starting from 3, going until 10, summing 'em up, and dividing. This seems like a really non-pythonic way and considering the functionalities Numpy offers, i thought maybe there is a shorter way using some Numpy magic. Any suggestion is much appriciated

Comment: Use a slice: A=(an array) then `sl_a=A[3:10]` then `av=sl_a.sum()/len(sl_a)` or use `np.mean(A[2:10])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access all elements between two indices `i` and `j` you can use slicing:

```
slice_of_array = array[i: j+1] # use j if you DO NOT want index j included
```

and the average is calculated with [`np.average`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html), but in your case you want to weight with the number of elements, so you can just use the [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
import numpy as np
mean_of_slice = np.mean(slice_of_array)
```

or all in one go (using your indices):

```
i = 3
j = 10
np.mean(array[i: j+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

np.mean(yourarray[3:11])
```

Assumed your array name is "yourarray"